# How can I check for a specified header file in Waf?

Tags: waf

I'm using waf to build a C program. I'd like to check for the existence of a particular header file during the configuration phase. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, a bit of googling found the answer to my question: You can use the `check` method on Configuration objects, like so:

```
def configure(conf):
    conf.check(header_name="stdbool.h")
```